# Share Values upstream in a nested cloudformation stack possible?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there some way to pass on Values form a child stack to a parent stack? All I found was to pass values down, but never up, that would unfortunately not correspond with my stack architecture. I could use cross-referencing with eXport/Import but would rather keep the nested stack if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't that create some sort of circular reference between your stacks? Each one will have to be deployed for the other one to import the value

Comment: I Tried @aerioeus way but not worked! Then i changed `!Ref` by `!GetAtt` its worked! `!GetAtt [SomeChildStack, Outputs.MyOutput]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely gather outputed values from a child stack and use them in the parent stack.

For example:

```
# parent stack
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  SomeChildStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AWS CloudFormation Stack Parameters
      TemplateURL: !Ref SomeTemplateUrl

  SomeOtherResource:
    Type: AWS::AnyOther::Resources
    Properties:
      SomeProperty: !Ref SomeChildStack.Outputs.MyOutput
```

And in `SomeChildStack`:

```
# The template used for SomeChildStack
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: !Ref 'LoggingBucket'
        LogFilePrefix: testing-logs
Outputs:
  MyOutput:
    Value: !Ref 'S3Bucket'
    Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket.
```

The tricky thing to remember is adding the `Outputs` when referencing the [`AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#w2ab1c21c10d210c19).

Note that this will make `SomeOtherResource` depend on `SomeChildStack`, so `SomeOtherResource` won't be created until `SomeChildStack` has been created.

Comment: Merci, wouldnt it make Sense then to add a DependOn in the SomeotherResource?

Comment: Not in this case. When using `!Ref` in `SomeOtherResource`, there is an [implicit dependency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html), so adding `DependsOn` isn't necessary

Comment: Merci, didn’t know that.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and the accepted answer (using !Ref) didn't work. CloudFormation wouldn't deploy the stack.

What did work for us is:

```
!GetAtt [NestedStack, Outputs.MyOutput]
```

Parent stack:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  NestedStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Ref NestedStackTemplateUrl

  ResourceInParentStack:
    Type: AWS::AnyOther::Resources
    Properties:
      SomeProperty: !GetAtt [NestedStack, Outputs.MyOutput]
```

Nested stack:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'MyBucketName'
      ...

Outputs:
  MyOutput:
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
    Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket.
```