# Import value from nested stack in Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CF stack and i need to import value from nested stack to another CF stack.

```
    "TargetGroup":{ 
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "SwaggTG"
       },
       "Export": {
                "Name": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-TargetGroup"
                }
        }
     },
```

```
 "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${RootStackName}-ApiTargetGroup"}
```

The problem is that OtherStackName is the root Stack and have 3 nested stacks and i need to access to the second one to get the VAR exported.

How can i do it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to export a value from a nested stack and import that value into one of the other nested stacks, also built from the same main/root stack?

Comment: See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230972/1706504) question and the answer there. Does that help?

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry if wasnt clear. I have 1 stack with 3 nested stacks and one of these nested stacks have an output exported but i need to get this output from another independent stack, and i dont know how to access to this output of the nested stack..